# Convert string in JSON object into PDF file

Tags: json, pdf

I have an API which returns a JSON value that should give me everything I need to create a PDF file. It appears to be a zip of a PDF, but I'm confused what exactly this is. What options do I have for converting this value into a PDF? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, K J. Silly question: how would I save a string as binary.zip? Do I literally copy the whole thing from "FORMAT-ZIP3..." to the end into a plain text file and save that file as binary.zip? By the way, there is no documentation, and the vendor is being non-responsive.

Comment: Thanks very much, K J, for the detailed advice. We were able to use this to convert the value into a document.